# Computer wakes up almost immediately if wol flag is set to anything else than d

Tags: wake-on-lan

I have the puzzling problem with a new NAS I am setting up.

First of all, I checked

`cat /proc/acpi/wakeup | grep enabled`

and disabled everything from waking up the system except for the two NICs it has.
Then, if I set using ethtool the wol flag to d which disables everything, the NAS can go to sleep and stay asleep indefinitely.

However, if I set the wol flag to anything else, the NAS will sleep but wake up almost instantly, like I pressed the power button right after it has slept.

I have tried other wol flags like u and b, both did the same to cause the NAS to wake up instantly. What maybe set to fix this?

Comment: try the [Magic Packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Magic_packet) mode (g).

Comment: Thanks, totally the case. I was just brain-fogging thinking the mode g (magic packet) was "packet-matched" meaning it will just wake up by network activity, turns out it was the opposite pretty much.